# Timer Countdown em PHP que interage com o javascript

Tags: php

Eu estava procurando um caminho para tentar fazer um timer em php que sera acionado assim que o usuario entrar na pagina, e quando ele trocar de aba(com a funcao $(window).focus e $(window).blur do jquery), o javascript aciona a funcao de pausar o timer que foi acionado. Quando ele voltar a aba, o javascript aciona a funcao de despausar o timer novamente.

Eu cheguei nesse codigo daqui com o javascript:

```
var timer = 60;

function startTimer(){
    timer = timer - 1;
  $("#countdowner").html(timer);
}

var timerInterval;
$(window).focus(function() {
    if (!timerInterval)
        timerInterval = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
    timerInterval = 0;
});
```

E nao tenho a minima ideia de como resolver isso com o php, ja que eu nao posso fazer um loop com a funcao "sleep"

Comment: E porque não usar for em php, que é uma estrutura de repetição que acredito que seja a melhor para este caso.

Comment: @Nagasaki não tem sentido usar for e repetição, o que ele quer é outra coisa, o que ele quer é um temporizador, mas o problema aqui é que o autor não entende aonde esta o back-end e o front-end, o que ele quer é tecnicamente inviavel e sem sentido, em web quase tudo é HTTP, "requisição e resposta"

Comment: A siiiimm, tinha entendido outra coisa, agora fiquei confuso em saber para que essa função que ele quer desenvolver será útil.